# Using data member pointer as template parameter in MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I want to use a member pointer to a data member as a template argument, as in the following:

```
class Node { };

template <typename T, Node T::*member>
class List { };

class Test {
private:
    Node node_;
public:
    typedef List<Test, &Test::node_> Registry;
};

int main() { }
```

This works just fine using G++, but Visual Studio Express 2013 complains with the following error messages:

```
Error   1   error C2327: 'Test::node_' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator  c:\temp\msvctest\msvctest\main.cpp  10  1   MsvcTest
Error   2   error C2065: 'node_' : undeclared identifier    c:\temp\msvctest\msvctest\main.cpp  10  1   MsvcTest
Error   3   error C2975: 'member' : invalid template argument for 'List', expected compile-time constant expression c:\temp\msvctest\msvctest\main.cpp  10  1   MsvcTest
```

How can I get Visual Studio to accept `&Test::node_` as a template parameter?

Comment: It also gets compiled on VS2012: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg VS really is getting worse... Probably a compiler bug then? Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: not sure... I simply cannot reproduce it (have no VS2013 on my machine)...

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly this is a compiler bug, which will be fixed "in upcoming release of Visual C++".

[Bug report and reply from Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1231858/compile-error-when-using-data-member-pointer-as-template-parameter)